# Reference adjacent cell for 'maximum' value when adding Data Bars using Excel Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Using Conditional Formatting in Excel, I wish to reference the adjacent cell for a set of cells when setting the `maximum` value for a data bar.

For example, take the simple table below. What I wish is to show a data bar that is 30/100 in cell `B2`, 200\200 in `B3` and 100\150 in `B4`.

```
    A        B
1 | To Pay | Paid |
3 |   £100 |  £30 |
4 |   £200 | £200 |
5 |   £150 | £100 |
```

However, Excel will not allow relative references when using a Data Bar, meaning I can only compare each cell in column `B` to other cells in column `B`, which in my use case is entirely pointless.

What I can do is add a rule for each row that references a single cell as the `maximum` value; e.g. I can add a CF Rule to cell `B2` to uses a formula to reference `A2` as the `maximum`. However, that means I have to add a rule for each row in column `B` (approximately 350 right now), which will be prone to error and will require a lot of maintenance.

Is there a way of achieving this in Excel using a single CF Rule?

---

#### Desired Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible without VBA.
Data Bar rules must refer to the contents of cells in which data bar is placed.
To compare them you must calculate ratios in another column and place data bar there. Calculated ratios may be optionally hidden.
[image: Data Bar]

Solution with VBA code:

```
Sub AddDataBars()
    Dim c As Range
    ' select the column range to be formatted
    For Each c In Selection
        c.FormatConditions.Delete
        With c.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
            .ShowValue = True
            .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
            .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueFormula, _
                newvalue:="=" & c.Offset(, -1).Address
            .BarColor.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) ' 5287936
            .BarFillType = xlDataBarFillSolid
        End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: That is what I feared, so I have already added an additional `% Paid` column and used that. It seems that many people have wanted to use Data Bars in this way, hopefully it's something that MS will sort out soon as using it in this way really isn't particularly useful in most situations.